# MATLAB: difference between Multithreading and Multicore

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I have an i7-M620 processor that have 2 physical cores and 2 threads (multi-threaded CPU) per core (a total of 4 threads). When I use the MATLAB Parallel Computing Toolbox, I can only open 2 pools and not 4. Here is the code:

```
matlabpool(2)
parfor i = 1:20
    Test(i) = i^2;
end
matlabpool close
```

- Could someone explain why?
- Am I doing multithreading or multicore computation here?
- Is it possible to do both with MATLAB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got around this (with my core i5 with 2 cores and 4 threads) by editing the "local" configuration for the parallel computing stuff:

1. Go to `Parallel->Manage Cluster Profiles`
2. Depending on you Matlab version, you'll need to `Validate` the `local` profile before changing anything.
3. Click `edit` and change the `NumWorkers` variable to suit your needs.

Then you can start `matlabpool` like this:

```
matlabpool local
```

Note I have never gotten a speedup using `parfor`. Matlab's overhead has always outweighed the benefits. What I'm saying is: benchmark your code first, then decide if `parfor` (or other parallel stuff) works for you or not.

Comment: On 2-core machines, I have never seen much speed-up either, though you may simple need to pack more stuff inside your loop. With processes where every iteration takes ~1min, I get linear speed-up on my 8-core workstations. Note that more recent i7's seem to have quite a bit lower overhead as well.

Comment: Hyperthreading will give you a significant boost if your tasks are I/O bound. You can also just use `matlabpool 4` to quickly open a pool with 4 workers.

Comment: @reve_etrange that command used to work on my old Core2 laptop, but if I want more than the default 2 on my machine, I need to change the configuration to allow 4. I suppose two cores is not enough for Matlab. This is still Matlab's fault anyhow, I can manually do the same in C++ and get the desired speedup easily.

Comment: @Rubenvb & Jonas: Actually I do get speedup in most CPU intensive algorithms, however its never a 2x speedup and I understand that. But if I understand the answer relative to HT, then I cannot use HT explicitly? and even with 4 threads, I can only open 2 Matlab pools? -I appreciate it.

Comment: I apologize for the last comment. I was actually able to open 4 matlab pool with the I7 M620 (hyper-threaded double core CPU) using Rubenvb's method. At the end, I am really getting ~15-20% of performance increase by opening 4 pools instead of 2. ~70-90% of performance increase with 2 Matlabpools vs 1 Matlabpool . And interestingly around 15% Decrease of performance when using 1 Matlabpool (with parfor) compared to no Matlabpool (for only).

Answer (score 4):

For a parallel configuration, this is the error thrown when requesting more workers than the default:

> The default value of `NumWorkers` for a local cluster is the number of
>   cores on the local machine. To run a communicating job on more workers than this , increase the value of the NumWorkers property for the cluster.

You can remedy that by modifying the `'local'` profile cluster properties, that effectively control the default number. From [PCT R2013a documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/saveprofile.html):

```
myCluster = parcluster('local'); 
myCluster.NumWorkers = 4; % 'Modified' property now TRUE 
saveProfile(myCluster);   % 'local' profile now updated,
                          % 'Modified' property now FALSE
```

Then `matlabpool open` will give you the (default) num. of workers, while `matlabpool(n)` will give you `n` workers, up to the above set maximum/default (`n<=4`). You can check the number of currently open workers by:

```
matlabpool('size')
```

or from the [indicator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/matlabpool.html) icon at the lower-right corner of your desktop, e.g. [image].

Answer (score 1):

My desktop station has one i7-2600 CPU, and the OS is the newest *Linux Mint*. I have tested parallel computing of MATLAB 2012b, which by default the NumWorker is 4 (the core number of i7-2600), I modified the local cluster profile to be 8 of the value of NumWorker, then I did the comparison with the workers setting to be 4 and 8 (just as @rubenvb posted).

The results show that in the serial mode, the time consuming is about *429* sec, while in the parallel mode (with matlabpool open 4) the time consuming is about *254* sec and *218* sec for 8 workers, i.e. boosted by *40.79%* and *49.18%*, respectively.

And I further investigated my code carefully, and found that inside the parallel body, MATLAB vectorization optimization is also implemented, i.e. extra CPU resource is required for such kind of boosting, thus for the NumWorkers of 8 case (i.e. hyper-thread enabled), it do not have enough idle CPU resource to boost vectorization, in some degree it is CPU resource competition, which reduce the parallel efficiency. This is also the reason that when NumWorkers of 4 almost with the equal boosting efficiency.

The conclusion is that parallel computation in MATLAB is quit helpful and simply to implement but should be used carefully, this is all my personal opinion.