# Running two threads at the same time

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to know if a program can run two threads at the same time (that is basically what it is used for correct?). But if I were to do a system call in one function where it runs on thread A, and have some other tasks running in another function where it runs on thread B, would they both be able to run at the same time or would my second function wait until the system call finishes?

Add-on to my original question: Now would this process still be an uninterruptable process while the system call is going on? I am talking about using any system call on UNIX/LINUX.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Multi-threading and parallel processing are two completely different topics, each worthy of its own conversation, but for the sake of introduction...

*Threading*:
When you launch an executable, it is running in a thread within a process.  When you launch another thread, call it thread 2, you now have 2 separately running execution chains (threads) within the same process.  On a *[single core microprocessor (uP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-core)*, it is possible to run multiple threads, but not in parallel.  Although conceptually the threads are often said to run at the *same time*, they are actually running consecutively in time slices allocated and controlled by the operating system.  These slices are interleaved with each other.  So, the execution steps of thread 1 do not actually happen at the same time as the execution steps of thread 2.  These behaviors generally extend to as many threads as you create, i.e. packets of execution chains all working within the same process and sharing time slices doled out by the operating system.

So, in your *system call* example, it really depends on what the system call is as to whether or not it would finish before allowing the execution steps of the other thread to proceed.  Several factors play into what will happen: Is it a blocking call? Does one thread have more priority than the other.  What is the duration of the time slices?

Links relevant to *threading* in C:
[SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c)
[POSIX](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)
[ANSI C](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/150368-multi-threading-pure-c.html)

*Parallel Processing*:
When multi-threaded program execution occurs on a multiple core system (multiple uP, or multiple multi-core uP) threads can run concurrently, or *in parallel* as different threads may be split off to separate cores to share the workload. This is one example of parallel processing.

Again, conceptually, parallel processing and threading are thought to be similar in that they allow things to be done *simultaneously*.  But that is concept only, they are really very different, in both target application and technique.  Where threading is useful as a way to identify and split out an entire task within a process (eg, a TCP/IP server may launch a worker thread when a new connection is requested, then connects, and maintains that connection as long as it remains), parallel processing is typically used to send smaller components of the *same task* (eg. a complex set of computations that can be performed independently in separate locations) off to separate resources (cores, or uPs) to be completed simultaneously.  This is where multiple core processors really make a difference.  But parallel processing also takes advantage of multiple systems, popular in areas such as *[genetics](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12270898)* and *[MMORPG](https://hadean.com/blog/mmorpgs-part-1-its-time-to-rethink-game-architectures/)* gaming.

*Links relevant to parallel processing in C*:
*[OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/)*
*[More OpenMP](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/c_src/openmp/openmp.html)* (examples)
*[Gribble Labs - Introduction to OpenMP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjLhZuFncLTAhVkxlQKHXw-DWMQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.ucy.ac.cy%2Fcourses%2FEPL372%2FSpring2016Files%2FEPL372_Lab5_OpenMP_Intro.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF9Mn4GORzbA0hbSpr5GO9aH70kdw&sig2=pvffIDDEbI1fGZWz5C0hjw&cad=rja)*
*[CUDA Tookit from NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp)*

Additional reading on the general topic of threading and architecture:

This summary of threading and architecture barely scratches the surface.  There are many parts to the the topic.  Books to address them would *[fill a small library](https://www.google.com/search?q=books%2Bon%2Bthreading%2Band%2Bmulti%2Bcore&sxsrf=ALiCzsYi6aeLLbW3g-TP107j-iBB2Egq_A%3A1651149847302&source=hp&ei=F4xqYpG_D8TE0PEPtrufqAw&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYmqaJ_rOxzDfhFE8WFpxBRlNOZJEcaBn&ved=0ahUKEwjRpvfA5Lb3AhVEIjQIHbbdB8UQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=books%2Bon%2Bthreading%2Band%2Bmulti%2Bcore&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjEOoCECdQxApYxApgrhNoAXAAeACAAVaIAVaSAQExmAEAoAECoAEBsAEK&sclient=gws-wiz)*, and there are *[thousands of links](https://www.google.com/search?q=multithreading%2Band%2Bprocessor%2Barchitecture&sxsrf=ALiCzsax3SeMGsoqbaALQ6OdR6RaQEbQTA%3A1651149978642&source=hp&ei=moxqYvT8JLHB7gK7_aeYAg&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYmqaqmlgMOobc7zmaD8G7fRO9LjZD58-&ved=0ahUKEwj0scj_5Lb3AhWxoFsKHbv-CSMQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=multithreading%2Band%2Bprocessor%2Barchitecture&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjEOoCECdQsAxYsAxgpR5oAXAAeACAAVaIAVaSAQExmAEAoAECoAEBsAEK&sclient=gws-wiz)*. Not surprisingly within the broader topic some concepts do not seem to follow reason. For example, *[it is not a given that simply having more cores will result in faster multi-threaded programs](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/multi-core-and-multi-threading/)*.

Comment: Lets say we have at least two processors, would there be an instance where any system call can make the process uninterruptable to signals while at the same time have my other function run? You say "as to whether or not it would finish before allowing the execution steps of the other thread to proceed". Is this in a single processor? Because a multiprocessor would allow for both to run at the same time using threads correct? In a single processor it would be concurrent and so my other function would have to wait, is that what you mean?

Comment: The rules change with multi-processor/core capabilities.  Now calls/programs can be written to break up specific jobs to be performed on a specific core.  And yes, that would change the behavior of being able to call _blocking_ functions, and not having them stop things in your primary thread. There are many good posts on this topic, [including this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459354/matlab-difference-between-multithreading-and-multicore).

Comment: would the process be an uninterruptable process though? during the time of the system call

Comment: Yes, you could write an uninterpretable process using EITHER a thread or (better) splitting it off to another core.  Priorities on threads can be elevated.  The OS you are using will come into play.  If you are using Windows, raising the ***[priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** of a thread  has to be done with caution, _If a thread runs at the highest priority level for extended periods, other threads in the system will not get processor time._

Comment: Continued: This can cause problems.  Real time OS's, or better yet, external hardware, are better for some tasks, such as data sampling at a fast rate that requires no interruptions.

Comment: So with all that said the process would not be able to send other system calls/receive while waiting on the system call from function A correct? For example if we were to do a system call from function B while the system call from function A is still waiting, this would not be possible right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39092/discussion-between-ryyker-and-user2644819)

Comment: "When you launch an executable, it is running in a primary thread, within a process." - Maybe this is a bit offtopic, but imagine that my project consists of several processes running at the same time and communicating among them. Is it wrong to state that my project is multi-threading?

Comment: Semantics can cause inconsistencies in understanding.  In context for this post, a single process would show up in say Device Manager on Windows, or using `ps` command line in Linux for an executable, no matter whether it is single threaded or if it has launched many threads.  So, generally speaking, in this context, although you can have many `things` happening in a single executable, those things are usually not referred to as processes.  And unless you have explicitly spawned additional threads in your executable, it is likely still a single threaded process.

Comment: The idea of "primary" and "secondary" threads is arbitrary:  In some programming environments (e.g., in Java), all threads are peers. A Java program's first thread (a.k.a., the "main()" thread) has no more privileges than any other thread has, and there's nothing that could happen to the main thread that could not also happen to any other thread.

Comment: @jameslarge - agreed.  I did not mean to convey anything different. I just needed a way to distinguish between the threads while attempting to discuss them as independent execution chains. At the time I choose to say _call it a secondary thread_, but it may have been more correct to say: _call it thread 2_.  ( as I read over the post again, I see that indeed I did refer to them as _thread 1_ and _thread 2_ later on in the paragraph. )  In any case, I have edited to incorporate your observation.  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they would, at least potentially, run "at the same time", that's exactly what threads are for; of course there are many details, for example:

- If both threads run system calls that e.g. write to the same file descriptor they might temporarily block each other.
- If thread synchronisation primitives like mutexes are used then the parallel execution will be blocked.
- You need a processor with at least two cores in order to have two threads truly run at the same time.

It's a very large and very complex subject.

Comment: would the system call make the process an uninterruptable process while the system call is going on? Using any system call with UNIX/LINUX can we achieve this?

Comment: That would depend on the system call (and possibly some other details).

Answer (score 3):

The basics are simple, but the details get complex real quickly.

You can break a program into multiple threads (if it makes sense to do so), and each thread will run "at its own pace", such that if one must wait for, eg, some file I/O that doesn't slow down the others.

On a single processor multiple threads are accommodated by "time slicing" the processor somehow -- either on a simple clock basis or by letting one thread run until it must wait (eg, for I/O) and then "switching" to the next thread.  There is a whole art/science to doing this for maximum efficiency.

On a multi-processor (such as most modern PCs which have from 2 to 8 "cores") each thread is assigned to a separate processor, and if there are not enough processors then they are shared as in the single processor case.

The whole area of assuring "atomicity" of operations by a single thread, and assuring that threads don't somehow interfere with each other is incredibly complex.  In general a there is a "kernel" or "nucleus" category of system call that will not be interrupted by another thread, but thats only a small subset of all system calls, and you have to consult the OS documentation to know which category a particular system call falls into.

Comment: can you initiate a system call and receive on one thread while another system call on a separate thread is already waiting? Or does the waiting block all other system call as well?

Comment: That would depend on the system call and the system.  Generally a in-process request for, eg, a disk sector will not prevent, say, a network operation by a different thread.  But individual OSes have all sorts of often-silly restrictions.  The only "authority" (if there is one) is the "official" documentation.

Answer (score 3):

- If your computer has only a single CPU, you should know, how it can execute more than one thread at the same time.
- In single-processor systems, only a single thread of execution occurs at a given instant. because Single-processor systems support logical concurrency, not physical concurrency.
- On multiprocessor systems, several threads do, in fact, execute at the same time, and physical concurrency is achieved.
- The important feature of multithreaded programs is that they support logical concurrency, not whether physical concurrency is actually achieved.

Answer (score 1):

They will run at the same time, for one thread is independent from another, even if you perform a system call.

It's pretty easy to test it though, you can create one thread that prints something to the console output and perform a system call at another thread, that you know will take some reasonable amount of time. You will notice that the messages will continue to be printed by the other thread.

Comment: Now would this process still be an uninterruptable process while the system call is going on?

Comment: @user2644819 that depends at least on the actual system call and the operating system...

Comment: let me rephrase: Are there any system call on UNIX/LINUX that could achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "uninterruptable"? The OS can interrupt the process at any time it wants to...

Comment: In the end, you want your process not to be eligible to be interrupted by the OS? Is that so?

Comment: @fvdalcin - `The OS can interrupt the process at any time`. Can you substantiate that? i.e. can a situation occur that would counter what you said?

Comment: @fvdalcin, yes that is exactly it.

Comment: @ryyker since modern OS schedulers are preemptive, and internal timers are used to generate interruptions in the processor's execution flow, I don't see how the OS couldn't interrupt a process, since the OS has the required privilege levels in order to configure the timers.

Comment: @user2644819 why would you want to do that? Do you realize that if you achieve such a thing, it could be used as a security exploit, since if a process running at user privilege level could run into an infinite loop and halt the whole processor, then no one would be able to interrupt it.

Comment: my professor said that SIGKILL can't be stopped/caught and i wanted to find a way where we have a process that doesn't listen to SIGKILL/terminate itself because of it.

Comment: Well, I would love to find a way to do that too. If find out please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, A program can run two [`threads`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) at the same time.

it is called  [Multi threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29).

> would they both be able to run at the same time or would my second function wait until the system call finishes?

They both are able to run at the same time.

---

if you want, you can make thread B wait until Thread A completes or reverse

Comment: Now would this process still be an uninterruptable process while the system call is going on?

Comment: Should not necessary, But if your system call is `send()` or `recv()` type calls then this would cost data loss. you can interrupt system calls with the signals.

Comment: i dont want to interrupt the system calls. I just want to know if it is possible that it would go in an uninterruptable process while my other function is running.

Comment: Why all the answers saying the threads will run at the same time? That really depends on the situation (number of processors, operating system, functions being called, etc.). It is not simply a given that they will run simultaneously, for an arbitrary scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Two thread can run concurrently only if it is running on multiple core processor system, but if it has only one core processor then two threads can not run concurrently. So only one thread run at a time and if it finishes its job then the next thread which is on queue take the time.